# What is the best way to visualize range of data?

Tags: pandas, data, visualization

If I a have data like a bunch of classes where each class can have a different number of students, and each student has a grade (0-100), for example like this:

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'classes':["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b","b","b", "c", "c"],
                    'grades':[78, 28, 10, 3, 79, 91, 65, 51, 75, 89]})
```

What is the best way to visualize the range of grades within each class? I want to show that in class A, there is a range between 10 and 78, in B there is 3 and 91, in C there is 75 and 89. I was thinking of boxplot or violin plot but when I tried them I am not really sure. Is there such thing as a bar chart that can show range? Will that make sense?

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, so here I am.

Answer (score 1):

I believe boxplot or violin plot is a good idea and you could overlay datapoints with a bit of jitter to the former. See below an example in seaborn taken from a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797760/seaborn-stripplot-with-violin-plot-bars-in-front-of-points):

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, color="0.8")
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, jitter=True, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]